# Como itero un arraylist de una interfaz?

Tags: java, poo, arraylist, interface, programacion-asincrona

El problema me dice crear **tres clases no relacionadas por herencia**: Cuadrado,Rectangulo,rombo y que cada clase implemente una interfaz "Calculos", el cual debe tener un metodo calcularArea().
Con esto, crear un main en el que haga un ArrayList y añada objetos con referencia de cada una de las clases e itere atraves del objeto arraylist en forma polimorfica el metodo calcularArea() de cada objeto y mostrar su informacion.

Estoy haciendo de esta forma, con instanceof pero me indica que: *class Calculos.cuadrado cannot be cast to class Calculos.Calculos...*

La verdad no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal o si se podria hacer de otra forma, help (adjunto codigo para que tengan idea).

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Calculos> objs = new ArrayList<>();

    Cuadrado square = new Cuadrado("lineal", 10, 15);
    Rectangulo rect1 = new Rectangulo("lineal", 32, 20);
    Rombo romb = new romb("lineal", 45, 20);
    objs.add((Calculos) square);
    objs.add((Calculos) rect1);
    objs.add((Calculos) romb);

    for (Calculos obj : objs) {
        if (obj instanceof Cuadrado) {
            Cuadrado squa = (Cuadrado) obj;
            System.out.println(squa);
            System.out.println(squa.calcularArea());

        }
        else if (obj instanceof Rectangulo) {
            Rectangulo rect = (Rectangulo) obj;
            System.out.println(rect);
            System.out.println(rect.calcularArea());

        } else if (obj instanceof Rombo) {
            Rombo rombo1 = (Rombo) obj;
            System.out.println(rombo1);
            System.out.println(rombo1.calcularArea());
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te estás enredando solo, haces más de lo necesario...

```
 public static void main( String[] args ) {
    ArrayList<Calculos> objs = new ArrayList<>();

    Cuadrado square = new Cuadrado( "lineal", 10, 15 );
    Rectangulo rect1 = new Rectangulo( "lineal", 32, 20 );
    Rombo romb = new romb( "lineal", 45, 20 );

       // no es necesario realizar un "cast"
    objs.add( square );
    objs.add( rect1 );
    objs.add( romb );

    for (Calculos obj : objs) {

           // lo interesante de las interfaces, es que crean una ligadura del objeto 
           // con su método propio, aunque el programador no la vea
        System.out.println( obj.calcularArea() );
    }
}
```

Ahora bien, más allá de lo innecesario de tu implementación, funciona, porque no haces nada malo, solo es innecesario, así que si estás recibiendo mensajes de error, deberías revisar tus clases...
Te dejo una clase "barata", con la que probé el código.

```
class Cuadrado implements Calculos {
   int alto;
   int ancho;
   String tipo;

   Cuadrado( String tip, int anc, int alt ) {
      ancho = anc;
      alto = alt;
      tipo = tip;
   }

   public double calcularArea() {
      return 0.1;
   }
}
```

Tal vez te falto el "implements"?.

Comment: ey, si me faltaba eso:,) graciass. El estres

Comment: OJO: si en un cuadrado pedís el ancho y el alto, puede que no creen un cuadrado.

Comment: @jachguate, jajaja,eeso me pasa por hacer las cosas sin pensar, gracias por estar atento!!.

Comment: @Lisstalik, un placer ayudarte!.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varios detalles en tu código, te voy explicando:

1. Dado que los objetos implementan la interface, no hace falta que hagas un moldeado de tipo para agregarlos a la lista. Puedes agregarlos directamente a la lista, que java sabrá utilizar dicha interface:

   ```
   objs.add(square);
   objs.add(rect1);
   objs.add(romb);
   ```
2. Ya que quieres tratarlos polimórficamente, y ya tienes una lista de los objetos por la interfaz que te interesa, no tienes por qué intentar averiguar la clase a la que pertenecen ni hacer moldes de tipo tampoco. Ya que tienes una lista de `Calculos`, puedes invocar directamente el método a través de la interfaz, esa es toda la idea de las interfaces, así, puedes recorrer la lista de esta manera:

   ```
   for (Calculos obj : objs) {
       System.out.println(obj.calcularArea());
   }
   ```

   De hecho, podrías imprimir también el nombre de la clase (por ejemplo), así:

   ```
   for (Calculos obj : objs) {
       System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName() + " " + obj.calcularArea());
   }
   ```

Una de la ideas principales detrás del concepto de interfaces es justamente esta. Que puedas acceder a los métodos de un objeto sin conocer su clase. Esto permite escribir código de manera polimórfica, incluso mucho antes de que se escriban las clases que implementarán las interfaces y sin crear dependencias en este código polimórfico hacia las implementaciones particulares que se hagan de dichas interfaces.

Comment: Gracias por tu explicacion:,)